# Unable to get token values from passport-openidconnect

Tags: nestjs, single-sign-on, passport.js, openid-connect, okta

I am developing a NestJs application that acts as a Proxy Server.
My first task was to integrate Okta Single Sign On into our application. In order to do that, I went with a passport strategy 'openidconnect'
However after login is successful, I can not access the token from the validate method in OpenIDConnectStrategy class.

I was following this tutorial `https://developer.okta.com/docs/guides/sign-into-web-app-redirect/node-express/main/#create-a-web-application` and it was written for ExpressJs. I tried my best to port this implementation into NestJs

Passport OpenIdStrategy

```js
import { Profile, Strategy, } from 'passport-openidconnect'
import { PassportStrategy } from '@nestjs/passport'
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common'
import { AuthService } from '../auth.service'
import passport, { Passport } from 'passport';

const yourOktaDomain = ''
const clientID = ''
const clientSecret = ''


@Injectable()
export class OpenIDConnectStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy,) {
    constructor(private authService: AuthService) {
        super({
            issuer: `https://${yourOktaDomain}`,
            authorizationURL: `https://${yourOktaDomain}/oauth2/v1/authorize`,
            tokenURL: `https://${yourOktaDomain}/oauth2/v1/token`,
            userInfoURL: `https://${yourOktaDomain}/oauth2/v1/userinfo`,
            clientID: `${clientID}`,
            clientSecret: `${clientSecret}`,
            callbackURL: 'http://localhost:3000/auth/loginSuccess/',
            passReqToCallback: true,
            scope: 'offline_access openid profile',
        });
    }
    public async validate(issuer, profile: Profile, context: object, id_token, access_token, refresh_token, params, done: Function) {
        try {
            const jwt: string = await this.authService.validateOauthLogin(profile.id, 'okta');
            console.log(context.toString)
            return ({ jwt, id_token, access_token });
        }
        catch (err) {
            console.log(err)
        }
    }
}
```

```js
AuthModule.ts

import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AuthController } from './auth.controller';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { UserModule } from 'src/user/user.module';
import { JwtModule } from '@nestjs/jwt';
import { jwtConstants } from './constants';

import { PassportModule } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { LocalStrategy } from './local.strategy';
import { OpenIDConnectStrategy } from './strategy/openidconnect-strategy'

@Module({
imports: [UserModule,
PassportModule,
JwtModule.register({
global: true,
secret: jwtConstants.secret,
signOptions: { expiresIn: '120s' }

        })],
    controllers: [AuthController],
    providers: [AuthService, LocalStrategy, OpenIDConnectStrategy],
    exports: [AuthService]

})
export class AuthModule { }
```

Auth Controller

```js
import { Body, Controller, HttpCode, HttpStatus, Post, Get, Headers, UseGuards, Request, Response, Req, Query, Redirect } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { LocalAuthGuard } from '../auth/guards/local-auth.guard'
import { OidcAuthGuard } from './guards/oidc-auth.guard';
@Controller('auth')
export class AuthController {
    constructor(private authService: AuthService) { }

    @UseGuards(OidcAuthGuard)
    @Get("/oidc")
    async oidc(@Request() req, @Response() res, @Headers() headers) {
        // return req;
    }

    @UseGuards(OidcAuthGuard)
    @Get('/loginSuccess')
    async oidcLogin(@Request() req, @Response() res, @Headers() headers) {
        console.log(req.user);
        console.log("Request =>>")
        console.log(req)
        res.redirect('http://localhost:3000/auth/redirectLogin/' + req.user.id);
    }
}
```

OIDC Authguard

```js
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AuthGuard } from '@nestjs/passport';

@Injectable()
export class OidcAuthGuard extends AuthGuard('openidconnect') {}
```

What am I doing wrong here?